# Migrate google Oauth1 to OAuth2 using unsigned-request flow

Tags: java, google-oauth

I'm trying to use the Unsigned-request flow as [documented](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration) (note this is not the signed request flow) and only get an HTTP 400: { "error": "invalid_request"} back. Here is the Java code I'm using (Apache HTTP Client 4.2.x).

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
httpPost.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", getClientId()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", getClientSecret()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", getScope()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", getOauthConsumerKey()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_secret", getOauthConsumerSecret()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", getOauthToken()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token_secret", getOauthTokenSecret()));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Sample Request/Response

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

oauth_consumer_secret=consumerSecret&oauth_consumer_key=consumerKey&oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=tokenSecret&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&scope=http%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F+http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1
```

Response

```
Status: 400 Bad Request

{
    error: "invalid_request"
}
```

Comment: Can you add a sample HTTP request generated by your code along the (400) HTTP response from Google?

Comment: Request
    POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     oauth_consumer_secret=secret&oauth_consumer_key=key&oauth_token=token&oauth_token_secret=tokensecret&client_id=id&client_secret=secret&scope=http%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F+http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file&grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1

Response
    Status: 400 Bad Request
    {
        error: "invalid_request"
    }

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, no. It's broken AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the `HttpPost.setEntity` method, however it appears it is setting the post body, not the headers as required by an OAuth 2.0 request. From the documentation you linked:

```
...
Authorization: OAuth realm="example",
           oauth_consumer_key="9djdj82h48djs9d2",
           oauth_token="kkk9d7dh3k39sjv7",
           oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
           oauth_timestamp="137131201",
           oauth_nonce="7d8f3e4a",
           oauth_signature="bYT5CMsGcbgUdFHObYMEfcx6bsw%3D"

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1&client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
```

You can see that **oauth_*** goes into the HTTP request header while **grant_type**, **client_id**, **client_secret** and **scope** should be in the HTTP body.

Comment: That is the signed request flow. If you keep reading past that in the documentation I linked you will see the "Unsigned-request flow for migration" which is what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the unsigned-request flow, the OAuth 1.0 access token is revoked immediately after a refresh token is issued. **This flow is allowed only for native applications. Requests from web applications that use this flow are denied.**